# Analysing algorithm with big theta

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

[image]

I have to say the time-complexity for these three algorithm. 
Is it possible someone can see if they're correct?

I'm also unsure as to how I find theta?

I know theta is the average of big-O and Omega. But I feel like it's basically the same when it comes to analysing code and writing it in big-O notation.

Comment: 1st and 3rd are correct. 2nd isn't as your complexity is linear in `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first one seems correct with below explanation, definition of Θ notation is as below

```
Θ(g(n)) = {f(n) : there exists c1,c2,n0 such that
                 0 <= c1*g(n) <= f(n) <= c2*g(n) given c1,c2,n0 > 0}
```

Here in 1st snippet we should look for f(n) which is

```
f(n)= n/3 + n/5 = 8/15*n
```

To find g(n) if we assume that c1=0.5,c2=2,n0=15(since divisible by both 3 and 5)
then below will be the cases

```
when n=15, 0<=c1g(n)<=f(n)<=c2g(n)  =>  0<=c1g(n)<=1*8/15*15<=c2g(n)  =>  0<=0.5*g(n)<=8<=2*g(n)
when n=30 0<=0.5g(n)<=16<=2g(n)
when n=90 0<=0.5g(n)<=48<=2g(n) ...so on

when n=17 0<=0.5g(n)<=9<=2g(n)
when n=20 0<=0.5g(n)<=10<=2g(n)
```

Hence g(n) = n seems appropriate choice and since we could demonstrate one combination of c1,c2 and n0 that demonstrates the definition to be correct, **g(n)=n** is acceptable answer.